# can't get correct checkbox value

Tags: jquery, jsp

My check box in my jsp is defined as:

```
<td class="text">
  <html:checkbox styleClass="onGoing" property="user.onGoing" onclick="hideInfo();" />    
    On Going
</td>
```

And in my js file:

```
function hideInfo() {
    if ($("[name='user.onGoing']").is(':checked')) 
    {
        alert('checked');
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
}
```

but it always shows up / enters as checked.

I've even tried testing as

```
if ($('user.onGoing').is(':checked')) { 
 .. .. .
}
```

but that doesn't work. When I look using developer tools, it's almost as if the dom isn't updating. How can I get the correct value of the check box?

Comment: Is `property` rendered as `value` or `name` attribute?

Comment: @Vohuman, a name. It's rendered as <input type="checkbox" name="user.onGoing" value="on" onclick="hideInfo();" class="onGoing">

Comment: Do you have more than one checkbox? jQuery `is` returns `true` even if only one of the elements in the set matches the given argument.

Comment: @Vohuman, yes, there is more than one checkbox on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for me

```
<input  type="checkbox" onclick="isChkChecked(this);"/>

        function isChkChecked(elm) {
        console.log($(elm).is(':checked'));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I was just over complicating it .. . I'll use this as my base, and build on it.

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid inline JS by all means and use the `change` event instead of `click`:

```
<td class="text">
  <html:checkbox styleClass="onGoing" property="user.onGoing" />    
    On Going
</td>
```

And JS:

```
$(':checkbox.onGoing').on('change', function() {
    if( this.checked ) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below snippet to get the value of checkbox if using jquery

```
 <html:checkbox styleClass="onGoing" property="user.onGoing" onclick="hideInfo(this)" /> 

 $("#check-demo").click(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {

       console.log($(this).val());     
     } else {
        console.log("false value");
     }
});
```

or if you want to use pure javascript then use code below

```
function hideInfo(element){
   console.log(element.value);
}
```

Comment: "Onclick dose'nt work in input type checkbox" === wrong.

Comment: I am sorry about that but try this snippet in your code this will get you the value on click.

Comment: No problem. That's not my question. Just a note, here one should listen to `change` event instead of `click`. Listening to `click` event of checkboxes is not a good idea.

Comment: can you just share the rendered html of checkbox.

Comment: @PuneetBharti, rendered is: <input type="checkbox" name="user.onGoing" value="on" onclick="hideInfo();" class="onGoing">

Comment: replace hideInfo() with hideInfo(this)
since rendered checkbox value is "on" you will always receive "on" as a value to this

Comment: @PuneetBharti, I've tried using the 2nd of our suggestions, but always get the value "on". In the first one, I've replaced check-demo with user.onGoing, but no luck with that one either.